# CloudFront Whole Site Delivery and urls contained within html

Tags: amazon-web-services, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

This is a simple question that possibly applies to all CDNs but I have not been able to find an answer to on the web or on the AWS site (http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/). Hopefully it is a simple answer for anyone familiar with CDNs or CloudFront and this might help others with understanding how this works.

If I were to use CloudFront for whole site delivery and set up an origin server (e.g. origin is www.myexample.com) then if I have an html file (example1.html) being served at www.myexample.com/example1.html and example1.html were to contain element that include an img tag with a src http://www.anothersite.com/anotherExample.jpg or even a S3 bucket source, then does this jpg from another source get cached in the cdn too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should connect the S3 bucket to a CloudFront distribution and use that links in the html code itself. I may be wrong, but I don't see how a CDN might be able to cache those links, as the client browser themselves request these resources based on the downloaded html code from the CDN.

Hence, in your example, only requests for myexample.com would go through your CloudFront distribution without any additional origin settings.

Edit: see @Skill M2 comment regarding adding multiple origin's for the same CloudFront distribution

Comment: This is what I would have presumed but I have read in a few places that this would not be necessary such as here: http://fideloper.com/cloudfront-full-site-delivery (quote below) and here http://blogs.gartner.com/lydia_leong/2012/05/14/amazon-cloudfront-gets-whole-site-delivery-and-acceleration/. These places don't really explain how this works though so I was hoping to ascertain whether this  true or wrong.

"While setting your entire site to be cached seems easier (you don't need to change the URL of assets in your HTML to a CDN URL!), there are a few very important considerations to make."

Comment: What I understand from that quote is that all internal assets are "cached" in the CDN, not assets from external sources.

Comment: Ok so this answer is broadly correct, the only thing to add is that you do not need another cloudfront distribution, it is possible to utilize the same distribution but set up more than one origin server (one for the web server, one for the s3 bucket) and then set up 'behaviors' by path pattern to determine which origin-server to use for each request to the cdn). See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesPathPattern